# React Component is running Fetch call on reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I navigate to localhost:3000/signup, the SignUp component is mounted and users can input their username, email, and password into a form, which then sends a fetch call to create a new user. Right now, this fetch call is being run as soon as the component is mounted. It should ONLY be run when the user clicks 'submit', hence the handleSubmit function. How do I prevent this from running when the component is mounted? What can be causing this issue?

Here is the code for this component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { SignUpFetch } from '../fetchCalls/SignUpFetch'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux' 

class SignUp extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {username: '', email: '', password: ''};
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        debugger
        SignUpFetch(this.state.username, this.state.email, this.state.password)
        this.setState({
            username: '', 
            email: '', 
            password: ''
        })

        this.props.history.push('/');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="SignUp">              
                <div className="sign-up-form-container">
                    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <p>
                        <b>Username</b>: <input type="text" name="username" onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} value={this.state.username} />
                        <br/><br/>
                        <b>Email</b>: <input type="text" name="email" onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} value={this.state.email} />
                        <br/><br/>
                        <b>Password</b>: <input type="text" name="password" onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} value={this.state.password}/> 
                        <br/><br/>
                        </p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up!"></input>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return {
          user: state.user
      }
  }

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, SignUpFetch)(SignUp))
```

Comment: Can you make code snadbox.. to me your code seems fine...

Comment: My guess is, that `SignUpFetch` is called on render since passed as second parameter to the react-redux `connect` function. This is by the way not used correctly. Look up how to use it [here](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect).

Comment: Thanks for y'alls help. How do you suggest I use the connect function in this context?